# Posts data to endpoint, trying not to use .Result on async methods

Tags: c#, comparative-review, async-await

I have a Send method that is working but want to refactor a portion where it is using PostAsync().Result and ReadAsStringAsync().Result. I've never written async methods before and don't feel I understand the core concept or pattern yet. Here is the original method:

```
public ServiceResult<string> Send(string tabDelimitedPOs)
{
    var result = new ServiceResult<string>();

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{User}:{Secret}");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
            
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;

    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(tabDelimitedPOs);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    response = httpClient.PostAsync(URL, httpContent).Result;

    httpContent.Dispose();

    result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        result.IsFaulted = false;
        result.ReturnedObject = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
    else
    {
        result.IsFaulted = true;
        result.FaultMessage = response.ReasonPhrase;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Would you critique the following refactor attempt? I've added two asynchronous methods.

```
public ServiceResult<string> Send(string tabDelimitedPOs)
{
    var result = new ServiceResult<string>();

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;

    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{User}:{Secret}");

    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        
    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(tabDelimitedPOs);
    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");

    Task<HttpResponseMessage> taskResponse = PostData(URL, httpContent);
        
    httpContent.Dispose();

    result.StatusCode = taskResponse.Result.StatusCode;

    if (taskResponse.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || taskResponse.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
    {
        result.IsFaulted = false;
        Task<string> taskString = ReadResponse(taskResponse.Result);
        result.ReturnedObject = taskString.Result;
    }
    else
    {
        result.IsFaulted = true;
        result.FaultMessage = taskResponse.Result.ReasonPhrase;
    }

    return result;
}

private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostData(string url, HttpContent content)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    return response;
}

private async Task<string> ReadResponse(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
}
```

Here is the rest of the class. This project is .NET Framework 4.5.2. The application is designed to run in a Server 2008 environment which I do not manage.

```
public class YoozAPI
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
    private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public YoozAPI() { }

    public static YoozAPI Initialize()
    {
        string jsonFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "YoozAPI.json");

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile);
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YoozAPI>(json);
    }

    public bool PostOrders(PurchaseOrders orders)
    {
        string tabDelimitedPOs = orders.GetTabDelimitedString();
        ServiceResult<string> result = Send(tabDelimitedPOs);

        if (result.IsFaulted)
            Log.RecordToDatabase("ExportReleasedPOs", string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, result.FaultMessage);

        return !result.IsFaulted;
    }

    // Code you've already seen above
}
```

Comment: What is .NET version? Also read [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) and about [Asynchronous programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: One more tip: `SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12` has no sense in .NET Framework 4.6 or newer, and has no effect (doesn't work for `HttpClient`) in .NET Core 3 or newer.

Comment: The version is .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review.

There's a lot of points that I may describe here, then I'll do it short.

#### Architecture

The wrong point here is sequence of instatiation settings for API helper class and the class itself. Originally instance created first, and only then the proberties are filled. It makes difficult to properly setup `HttpClient`.

I suggest to split settings and helper to reverse the instantiation order.

```cs
public class YoozApiSettings
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Secret { get; set; }
}
```

*Naming guidline: don't use uppercased names for names of more than 2 characters long. For example `IO` is fine but `URL` isn't. Renaming `URL` to `Url`. The same for the class names.*

#### Reading file

Here's a first occurance of a wrong `IDisposable` usage. You open the file `YoozAPI.json` but never close it. Let's fix.

**Original**

```cs
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

You may add `reader.Close()` or `reader.Dispose()`.

**Nearest fix**

```cs
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile);
string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Dispose()
```

But here's an issue. If `reader.ReadToEnd()` cause an exception, the file again will be never closed.

**Good fix**

```cs
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile);
try
{
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
finally
{
    reader.Dispose()
}
```

But C# has already implemented this pattern, you can use it with less code written.

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFile))
{
    string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Also .NET has a shortcut for this classic code pattern.

```cs
string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
```

Read more: [Using objects that implement IDisposable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects), [using statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

As a summary of above notes the `Initialize()` method will look like:

```cs
public static YoozApi Initialize()
{
    string jsonFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "YoozAPI.json");
    string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
    return new YoozApi(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YoozApiSettings>(json));
}
```

As you can see, I pass `YoozApiSettings` to `YoozApi` constructor.

Here's why.

#### Initializing `HttpClient`

`DefaultRequestHeaders` must be implemented once, right after `HttpClient` instance creation and before the first request sent.

```cs
private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

private YoozApi(YoozApiSettings settings) 
{
    httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false; // I'm not sure if it needed
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; // Remove this for .NET version 4.6 or higher
    var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{settings.User}:{settings.Secret}");
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);
}
```

- `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` also can be set once.
- No reason to render credentials per request as `User` and `Secret` never changes.
- `HttpClient.BaseAddress` is intended to set a root address to make easier futher requests. With base address `new Uri("https://myapi.com")` to call `https://myapi.com/method` you may write like `httpClient.GetAsync("method")` instead of whole URL.
- `private` constructor means you can create the class only through `Initialize()` method.

#### Asynchronous programming

All IO apis has thier awaitable methods. It makes easy to write asynchronous code that allows not to block threads while waiting. `.Result` blocks the calling thread, `await` not. Read more: [Asynchronous programming](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) (especially read about difference between IO-bound work and CPU-bound work there).

Awaitable method is method that returns `Task` or `Task<T>`, or any other type that implements awaitable pattern e.g. `ValueTask` of `ValueTask<T>` (available in .NET Core 3.1 and newer .NET). Awaitable method may be marked as `async`, may be not. To detect is the method awaitable look at its returning type, not at `async`.

To make the `await` able to work, the method must be implement State Machine pattern. C# compiler can implement the State Machine from a regular method automatically. Just add `async` keyword. Then `await` can't be used without `async`, `async` has no sense without `await` inside like State Machine for nothing.

```cs
private async Task<ServiceResult<string>> InternalSendAsync(string tabDelimitedPOs)
{
    var result = new ServiceResult<string>();
    using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(tabDelimitedPOs, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/", httpContent))
    {
        result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
        result.FaultMessage = response.ReasonPhrase; // you always have a ReasonPhrase as StatusCode
        result.IsFaulted = !response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            result.ReturnedObject = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return result;
    };
}
```

*Naming guideline: add `Async` suffix to the name of awaitable method (recommended by Microsoft, I find it useful too).*

In addition to above notes, `await` unwrap the returning result from `Task`. So it works like `.Result` but asynchronously.

You can see that I hid the method with `private` modifier as if it used only internally then no reason to expose it.

#### Usage

The reasonable question can apper "How can I use async method from sync method". The general answer: "You can call but you can't await it". For top-level methods that launches asynchronous work `async` keyword can be used with `void` returning type`.

Let's assume that you're implementing a Windows Forms app.

```cs
private readonly YoozApi api = YoozApi.Initialize();

private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (await api.PostOrdersAsync(orders))
        {
            // Success
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Always handle all possible exceptions in `async void` method otherwise you'll not see the fact of the occured exception. Visually nothing will happen.

#### The whole example

```cs
public class YoozApi
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    private YoozApi(YoozApiSettings settings) 
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{settings.User}:{settings.Secret}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Url);
    }

    public static YoozApi Initialize()
    {
        string jsonFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "YoozAPI.json");
        string json = File.ReadAllText(jsonFile);
        return new YoozApi(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YoozApiSettings>(json));
    }

    public async Task<bool> PostOrdersAsync(PurchaseOrders orders)
    {
        string tabDelimitedPOs = orders.GetTabDelimitedString();
        ServiceResult<string> result = await InternalSendAsync(tabDelimitedPOs);

        if (result.IsFaulted)
            Log.RecordToDatabase("ExportReleasedPOs", string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, string.Empty, result.FaultMessage);

        return !result.IsFaulted;
    }

    private async Task<ServiceResult<string>> InternalSendAsync(string tabDelimitedPOs)
    {
        var result = new ServiceResult<string>();
        using (HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(tabDelimitedPOs, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync("/", httpContent))
        {
            result.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
            result.FaultMessage = response.ReasonPhrase; // you always have a ReasonPhrase as StatusCode
            result.IsFaulted = !response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                result.ReturnedObject = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;
        };
    }
}
```

*Note: Windows Server 2008 R2 doesn't support TLS 1.2 by default but it can be enabled manually through Windows Registry. Anyway I recommend to update the [.NET Framework to 4.7.2 as it fully compartible with Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-472). The update won't affect other 4.5.2 apps.*

Comment: Thank you very kindly for this thorough response. Can I follow up and ask how to write a unit test for PostOrdersAsync? I've modified an existing test method of mine and it appears as if it doesn't even run.

Comment: Currently reading this. Please let me know if you have a good reference to read as well. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/november/async-programming-unit-testing-asynchronous-code

Comment: @CodenameCain `a unit test` unfortunately I didn't write tests a lot. Btw, nice article containing a lot of useful info.

Comment: Instead of public void MyTestMethod (not the real name, don't skewer me) I had to change the signature to public async Task MyTestMethod.